# Small (1 x 1) Android clock (widget)

Tags: gratis, android

Even when grouping icons, my Android home screen is becoming crowded.

I am looking for a 1 x 1 solution. I.e something that only takes up as much space as a standard icon.

Must be gratis and offer a 12 hour digital clock.

Not necessary, but welcome:

- black or transparent background
- date, although I realize that might be difficult to read (hmmm, maybe it could expand when I touch it and shrink back to 1 x 1 when I remove my finger? I ***like*** this idea; add weather forecast too)
- it doesn't have to be a widget. I could accept an app which updates its icon every minute to display the time (although it should preferably not update when the 'phone is locked or the icon is not on the screen which is currently being viewed). Failing that, (long) press to launch the in-built alarm clock
- see no reason why a clock app needs access to my contacts, camera, file systems, etc

I found one called [Nice Simple Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullium.nicesimpleclock&hl=en_GB&gl=US), but it truncates the right most digit when resized to 1 x 1 and I don't see a way to change the font.

Comment: Which launcher are you using, and are you willing to change launchers?  I know Total Launcher can do this without needing any additional apps.  The link to the gratis version is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.launcher2 and the link to the paid version is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.launcher2.key - I'm 95% certain the free version includes this functionality, but I've only used the paid version recently.

Comment: Launcher? None that I am aware of. Thanks for the tip. I will check it out

Comment: You're welcome.  Just FYI, pretty much every Android device with an integrated screen uses a launcher, but most people likely just use the default launcher included with the device.

Comment: I am familiar with the concept. My main interface with Windows is [Executor](https://executor.dk/). That  and [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) are the only way that I communicate with Windows (not explorer, start menu, run menu, etc). But, that's just a digression, sorry. I dimly remember using an Android launcher 3 or 4 'phones ago. I guess that it's time now to see which best suits me (efficiency, practicality & no bling).Thank again (+1)

Comment: If you're looking for an efficient launcher that maximizes practicality and has no bling, you may want to take a look at some of the launchers on F-Droid: https://search.f-droid.org/?q=launcher  There are several extremely efficient bare-bones open-source launchers available there.  I doubt any will be able to auto-generate a 1x1 clock widget because that's rather *blingy*, but perhaps one of those efficient launchers will obviate the need.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning your favorite tools to manage things in Windows.  I currently use different tools, but those both look so good I might switch.

Comment: ha ha - well, we are both, obviously, fans of finding a great app. Total Commander was the first piece of shareware I ever paid for, back in the early 90s. I have never regretted that purchase, although there are now rivals. [Double Commander]9https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) tries to be a cross-platform, open source, clone, and is probably 95%+ so.I personally prefer TC at home, but use DC at work, because of the licensing.  also love the [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) clipboard manager. And, for me, $10 for [TinySpell](http://www.tinyspell.com/) was a great investment :-)

Comment: Ask me for more, or recommend me some :-)

Comment: I'll set up a chat soon so we can, well, chat and share our experiences. :)  Sound good?

Comment: Sounds good! Is there any way that the site can set up a poll where users can vote for their favourite program in certain categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice Simple Clock is quite configurable. I was able to get a quite legible 1x1 display by reducing the text size from 30 to 22. The configuration option you need is Time Text Appearance, then select Text Size; adjust the Date Text Appearance in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, James, I missed the configuration options. For others: Download from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullium.nicesimpleclock&hl=en_GB&gl=US). Click the icon and select Widget, drag that to your home screen. Then, click the widget on the home screen (not he original icon) for settings. Voila, small, but legible, clock with time, plus day of week and date. What's not to like?